# jQuery Append codes doesn't append my divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to:

1. get the div.main-content (this is the main div)
2. append  from there
3. then find img class avatar-main and put the img url there
4. then get the h5 class fullName and put the fullName & the span class 
   userNameMain and put the username there, & the timePosted class there and put the time posted
5. then get the paragraph class tweetContent and put the text in there
6. Finally I'll append a static uls with classes:

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ativeTweets();
});

function ativeTweets(){
  var index = streams.home.length - 1;
  while(index >= 0){
    var tweet = streams.home[index];
    var $tweet = $('div.main-content');
    $tweet.append('<div class="box-content"></div>');
    $tweet.append('<img src="" align="left" class="avatar-main">');
    $tweet.append('<h5 class="fullNameMain"> <span class="userNameMain"> <span class="timePosted">* 5h</span></span></h5>');
    $tweet.append('<p class="tweetContent"></p>');
    $tweet.append('<ul class="activities">
                <li><span class="comment"></span> 48K</li>
                <li><span class="retweet"></span> 50K</li>
                <li><span class="heart"></span> 100K</li>
                <li><span class="msg"></span> 22K</li>
              </ul>');
    $('.box-content').find('.avatar-main').attr('src', 'img/' + tweet.user + '.jpg');
    $('.box-content').find('.fullNameMain').text(tweet.user);
    $('.box-content').find('span.userNameMain').text('@' + tweet.user);
    $('.box-content').find('span.timePosted').text(new Date());
    $('.box-content').find('.tweetContent').text(tweet.message);
    index -= 1;
  }
}
```

I am not sure but for some reason, these codes won't work and it doesn't append anything at all on the div:

```
<div id="main-content"></div>
```

ERROR:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Am i doing something wrong here? Please help!

Comment: any errors in the browsers **developer** tools console? because that isn't valid javascript as shown in the code block

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token but when I click on it. It doesn't show me any highlighted error. See screenshot: http://prntscr.com/h24izz

Comment: you can't have string literals span multiple lines

Comment: What do you mean? can you try to put the codes so I can see what you mean..

Comment: `$tweet.append('<ul class="activities">` .... see that unterminated string for example - see [dopcumentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#String_literals)

Comment: $tweet.append('<ul class="activities"></ul>'); I did this but still did not work.

Comment: what error are you getting now? how did you deal with the 5 following lines?

Comment: `var $tweet = $('div.main-content');` will attempt to select a div with class main-content, your div has an id main-content. Try doing var `$tweet = $('div#main-content');`

Comment: Ur are selecting the main **var $tweet = $('div.main-content');** by class name...it should be **var $tweet = $('div#main-content');** by Id

Comment: oh .... `'div.main-content'` ... looks for div with class including `main-content` ... you want `'div#main-content'` - oops, 2 others spotted the same mistake simultaneously :p

Comment: lol @wajeeh - the div has **id** of `main-content` so ...

Comment: @JaromandaX lol, I didn't notice that

Comment: good catch. But the tweet text is not working there.Mind chatting?

Comment: you're doing `$tweet.append('<p class="tweetContent"></p>');` but then you're looking for tweetContent inside of box-content `$('.box-content').find('.tweetContent').text(tweet.message);`

Comment: @KushPatel can we chat?

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues.

- First you attempt to use class not id in code.
- You cannot extend a string over multiple lines
- You append to the div but look in the box.  I put them in the box
- You can also cache the box ref when you create it (not strictly needed)
- You were using .text and overwriting the contained element

```js
$(function() {
  ativeTweets();
});
var streams = {};
 streams.home= [{user:"one",message:"on mess"},{user:"two",message:"on two mess"}];//just to run locally
function ativeTweets() {
  var scount = streams.home.length;
  var index = streams.home.length;
  while (index--) {
    var tweet = streams.home[index];
    var $tweet = $('#main-content');
    $tweet.append('<div class="box-content"></div>');
    var mybox = $tweet.find('.box-content').last();
    mybox.append('<img src="" align="left" class="avatar-main">');
    mybox.append('<h5 class="fullNameMain"> <span class="userNameMain"> <span class="timePosted">* 5h</span></span></h5>');
    mybox.append('<p class="tweetContent"></p>');
    mybox.append('<ul class="activities">' +
      '<li><span class="comment"></span> 48K</li>' +
      '<li><span class="retweet"></span> 50K</li>' +
      '<li><span class="heart"></span> 100K</li>' +
      '<li><span class="msg"></span> 22K</li>' +
      '</ul>');
    mybox.find('.avatar-main').attr('src', 'img/' + tweet.user + '.jpg');
    mybox.find('.fullNameMain').prepend(tweet.user);
    mybox.find('span.userNameMain').prepend('@' + tweet.user);
    mybox.find('span.timePosted').text(new Date());
    mybox.find('.tweetContent').text(tweet.message);
    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-content"></div>
```

Comment: how can I separate them one by one.